# Use addition in database SQL

Tags: sql, database, addition

Can I use addition in database?

For example: I have data inside database that is integer. It has a value of 5.

Is there a query that will add another 1 to that? So it will become 6.

Please help me I'm a beginner.

Comment: **[XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)**. Possible solution `UPDATE ... SET val = val + 1` or more probably you want to reinvent `INDENTITY/SEQUENCE/AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: I think the first one is good.

Comment: Add `1` number, not `'1'` string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most basic form of an update statement:

```
update the_table
  set the_column = the_column + 1
where the_column = 5;
```

Note that the above will update ***all*** rows where `the_colum` has the value 5. You most probably want to change the `where` clause to something different, e.g. by selecting only a *single* row by using a condition on the primary key column(s) of the table.

Check the manual of your DBMS for details, e.g.: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dml-update.html

Comment: how can i use this in php? $querry = mysqli_query($conn,"update the_table
  set the_column = the_column + '1'
where the_column = '5' ") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

Comment: @MarkKleinFermin: sorry, no idea. I don't use PHP - you should ask a **new** question for that.